# Is there a way to "program to interface" in scala

Tags: scala, traits

Is there a way to "program to interface" in scala?

I am new in Scala. I have a "trait" in scala and many classes extending that trait.  I am looking for a way on how to use the interface instead of the class directly.

Currently, I am doing :

```
val clazz = new MyClass()
```

where MyClass is extended from a trait.

I am looking for a way to return the interface as an instance from the factory mathods for generating classes. Is there a way?

Comment: Widening conversions in Scala work just like they would in Java. If `MyClass` implements a trait `Foobar` and your method has return type `Foobar`, you can return `clazz` just fine.

Comment: calling `asInstanceOf[MyClass]` breaks type safety and defeats the purpose of "program to interface"

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are talking about "programming to an interface", but in your example, you cast the value to a concrete subclass type using `asInstanceOf`, which is the *exact opposite* of programming to an interface.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you mean by "I am looking for a way to return the interface as an instance from the factory mathods for generating classes." You can only return objects from methods. But traits aren't objects, therefore you cannot return a trait from a factory method. (Well, you can obtain a reflective proxy for a trait using the Scala reflection API and return *that* …)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just request the type of the interface:

```
val clazz: MyInterf = new MyClass()
```

If you really want to hide the implementation, one approach is to create a companion for the trait:

```
trait MyInterf {
  ...
}

class MyClass extends MyInterf {
  ...
}

object MyInterf {
  def create: MyIntef = new MyClass()
}

// calling code
val impl = MyInterf.create
```

Comment: If I have 2 classes implementing this interface, how to change the create method to return the right instance based on the requirement? I am trying to understand  how to implement the facetory mathods

Comment: based on what requirement? If it's just during creation, you can pass a parameter to the `create` method. Beyond creation, if your calling code needs to be aware of what class is providing the implementation, then you're not really "programming to the interface"